What is a dart-y way to dynamically set which property to use, e.g. which style in a TextTheme?
Suppose I have class MyTextField which is just a wrapper for a TextField. I want to allow the caller to pass something (using a String below just for a placeholder) that will then determine, from the theme, which text style to use:
class MyTextField extends StatelessWidget {
    final String textStyle;
 
    MyTextField({super.key, required this.textStyle = 'displayLarge'});

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
         return TextField(
             readOnly: true,
             canRequestFocus: false,
             decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: const OutlineInputBorder(),
                  hintText: "My Hint Text",
             ),
             style: Theme.of(context).textTheme[textStyle],
        );
    }


Coming from python (not sure what the Dart equivalent of "pythonic" is), I'm reaching for __getattr__, where I can set a string value dynamically, but I'm not sure how to do this in Dart in a way that's not fighting with the type system.

Yeah, you can't do that in Dart, by design.  You can build up a method that takes a string and returns one of the properties via a switch or something.  But you need to do the work.  Macros will eventually help.
